# how to resize ImageView height in androidstudio

Tags: android

I made dynamic widget(Image View) But I can't resize height !!

plz help me T_T

if I Click addButton , application call createwidget() method.

have a nace day!!

`private void createwidget(View view){`

```
    rimg=new ImageView(this);
    rimg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.avatar);
    rimg.setPadding(0,5,0,0);
    rimg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    rimg.setId(DYNAMIC_IMG_ID+dynamiccnt);

    rimg.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flag="";
            ClickListener(view);
        }

        {

        }});


    //lptvText_Property.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    addtext=new EditText(this);
    addtext.setId(DYNAMIC_TEXT_ID+dynamiccnt);
    addtext.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(230,230,230));
    addtext.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,140,0));
    addtext.setHeight(300);



    //addtext
    recipelinear.addView(rimg, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    recipelinear.addView(addtext, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    recipelinear.addView(addbtn);

}
```

Comment: When you add rimg view to recipelinear you can change MATCH_PARENT by a value in pixel for height ?

Comment: I didn't know that! thakyou I try it !!